# FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP giving null pointer exception when converting date to EST

Tags: hive, hdfs, hiveql

I am trying to convert a Date string to Timezone EST /EDT
I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myschema.timeZoneCheck1 (timeCol String)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n' 
LOCATION '/users/TestTimeZone/'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

and data in the HSFS file is as follows:

timeZoneDateCol
2015/12/08
2015/07/06

This is the required format needed:

If date is 2015/12/08 the I should get value like 2015120811 ( as it falls in EST)

If date is 2015/07/06 then I should get value like 2015070610(as it falls in EDT)

TRied this with hive function:

```
Select timeCol,FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(timeCol, 'EST') from myschema.timeZoneCheck1;
```

and this is the Stacktrace of error:

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"timecol":"2015/12/08"}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"timecol":"2015/12/08"}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:507)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:170)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating Converting field timecol from UTC to timezone: 'EST'
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:497)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFFromUtcTimestamp.evaluate(GenericUDFFromUtcTimestamp.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:77)
        ... 13 more


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you read the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) of that function carefully? And did you ever work with the binary DATE and TIMESTAMP Hive data types?

OK, these are rhetorical questions. In a nutshell, Hive recognises date and time literals (i.e. Strings containing a date/time representation) **using ODBC format exclusively**:

- `'2015-12-31'` can be compared to a DATE (implicit conversion)
- `date'2015-12-31'` is even more explicit and is more or less a SQL
  standard
- `'2015-12-31 23:59:59'` can be compared to a TIMESTAMP (implicit
  conversion)

*I could have said ISO instead of ODBC but, actually, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) uses a "T" between date and time. ODBC uses a space, more human-readable, more popular.*

So you just have to reformat your outlandish date format into an ISO/ODBC date, paste a dummy "midnight" time, and voila:

```
select OUTLANDISH_DATE,
  from_utc_timestamp(concat(regexp_replace(OUTLANDISH_DATE, '/', '-'), ' 00:00:00'), 'EST') as ZONED_TIMESTAMP
from WHATEVER

-- outlandish_date  zoned_timestamp
-- 2015/12/08       2015-12-07 19:00:00
```

Comment: BTW, the linux `date` utility works the same way, although you cannot change the default TZ... and the "midnight" trick is not necessary e.g. `date --date '2015-12-08 Z' '+%F %T %Z'` yields `2015-12-08 01:00:00 CET` on my Dev box.

Comment: thanks Samson! I am a newbie ..Is there some way to check if the current time stamp lies in EST or EDT?

Comment: The system clock does not care about timezones, the ticks refer to the "Unix Epoch" (milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT) and resynchronize with atomic clocks from time to time using NTP. And since a computer has no way to know on which part of the world it is running, the system time zone is **set arbitrarily** by the SysAdmin. If you run a server in India for a bank in Los Angeles, maybe it's set for Los Angeles time, maybe for India time, maybe for UTC to avoid misunderstandings. Bottom line, **you cannot know for sure in which time zone lies your server**.